# Mathematical Explanation of Mathematica Summation ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+2)!}\zeta(2n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-zeta, wolfram-alpha

> From a mathematical point of view, what phenomena that most likely Mathematica Wolfram encountered when [calculating](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BFactorial%5B2n-1%5DZeta%5B2n%5D%2FFactorial%5B2n%2B2%5D,%7Bn,1,Infinity%7D%5D):
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+2)!}\zeta(2n)\,=\,\color{red}{\frac{2\log(2\pi)-3}{8}+\frac{\zeta(3)}{8\pi^2}} $$
> which is incorrect.

While calculating the sum from [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304769/show-that-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac-zeta2kk12k1-frac12), I noticed that Wolfram result is containing ${\small\,\frac{\zeta(3)}{8\pi^2}\,}$, which is incorrect. Although I realized that this could be a bug, I started to wonder if there are any logical explanation behind this miscalculation! Has Wolfram algorithm encountered something similar to [Riemann Rearrangement Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)?

Doing more investigations, it turns-out that Wolfram is incorrectly miscalculating the closed form of an entire class of zeta summation, except the last case which is correct.
$$ \small \begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(\alpha\,n)}{(n+a)(n+b)\dots} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[A\frac{\zeta(\alpha\,n)}{n+a}+B\frac{\zeta(\alpha\,n)}{n+b}+\dots\right] = \\ C+\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(\alpha\,n)-1}{(n+a)(n+b)\dots} &= \color{darkgreen}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[A\frac{\zeta(\alpha\,n)-1}{n+a}+B\frac{\zeta(\alpha\,n)-1}{n+b}+\dots\right]\,+C} \end{align} $$
And with the appearance of this case (the last correct closed form), I believe there is a mathematical explanation regarding a correct summation method or algorithm that gives a kind of systematic incorrect closed form if it applied in a certain way. Appreciating if someone can explore this and alert us **regardless of any bug that may exist in any math app**. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Quite difficult to say what is really happening there. In my experience with old versions of Mathematica, I have seen $\text{NIntegrate}$ and $\text{N[Integrate]}$ yielding radically different outputs when dealing with elliptic integrals and the like. A non-legit rearrangement of some sort is likely.

Comment: Or maybe a bad management of the branches of the complex logarithm, or maybe... what happens if we compute such series through Euler-Maclaurin, and completely ignore the integral error term?

Comment: Or maybe it is just an intended lesson: *don't trust the machines too much*.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : The deference between the correct and incorrect answer is the term ${\,\frac{\zeta(3)}{8\pi^2}\,}$, I am wondering how to re-arrange the summation to generate such term.

Comment: It might be related to the factorial. Because  if we put the gamma function instead its evaluated correctly. [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D1+to+infinity+(%CE%93(2+n)+%CE%B6(2+n))%2F%CE%93(2n+%2B+3))

Comment: @Zacky : Nice observation! Being more precise, we have to change both factorials from nominator and denominator ${\small\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(2n)}{\Gamma(2n+3)}\zeta(2n)}$. Most probably Wolfram is starting now by simplifying ${\small\displaystyle\frac{\Gamma(2n)}{\Gamma(2n+3)}=\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)(2n+2)}}$. Okay, at least we now know that we shouldn’t start by this simplification.

Comment: The sum behavior, ${\small\displaystyle\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)(2n+2)}\sim\frac{1}{n^3}}$, explains somehow  the appearance of the term ${\small\displaystyle\zeta(3)}$.

Comment: Also note that $\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)(2n+2)} = 1/(4 (n + 1)) - 1/(2 n + 1) + 1/(4 n)$.

Comment: I know that `\displaystyle` often "looks better", but it should be avoided in the tilte.

Answer (score 6):

*Only a note.*

WolframAlpha can calculate $\enspace\text{Sum[Zeta[2n]*(2n-1)!/(2n+1)!,{n,1,Infinity}]}$

$\displaystyle \left(=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2n)(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}\right)\enspace$ *exactly*

but can only *approximate* $\enspace\text{Sum[Zeta[2n]*(2n)!/(2n+2)!,{n,1,Infinity}]}$

$\displaystyle \left(=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2n)(2n)!}{(2n+2)!}\right)$.

This is indeed strange, because the difficulty is about the same. *WolframAlpha has problems with slow converging series.*

Maybe the term $\,\,\text{$\zeta(3)/(8\pi^2$)}\,\,$ is by chance, because the calculation inaccuracy seems to be very close to this term at some point of the calculations.

It's interesting, that WolframAlpha calculates

$\,\,\text{Sum[Zeta[2n](2n-1)!/(2n+3)!,{n,1,Infinity}]}\,\,$ 
$\displaystyle \left(=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2n)(2n-1)!}{(2n+3)!}\right)$

exactly including $\,\text{$\zeta(3)/(8\pi^2$)}$, here $\,\text{$9\zeta(3)/(72\pi^2$)}\,$ .

Comment: Good note. Thanks.

Comment: @HazemOrabi: You are welcome. :) But I am sorry, for better informations I've to know how WolframAlpha works exactly.

Comment: @HazemOrabi: Thanks for the bounty, it's very kind of you. :)

Comment: U R Welcome! Thanks for your contribution.